# How to break data-binding after first rendering in Angular?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, data-binding, model

I've got a page in my website in which I want to show a checkbox. I only want to show the checkbox if the model is initially false. So I wrote this (**this was my initial code, but it was a simplified version of what I have myself. I updated the code in the snippet at the end of this question to show the problem**):

```
<div ng-if="!the_field">
    <input ng-model="the_field" type="checkbox">
</div>
```

The problem is that if I click the checkbox, it disappears. That of course makes sense, but I have no idea how to solve this.

So what I basically want is to show the checkbox if the model was false upon rendering the HTML. But after that I want to somehow break the databinding so that the checkbox remains on the page even if the model changes to true.

Does anybody know how I can achieve this? All tips are welcome!

[EDIT]
I would prefer doing this from within the template, so that I don't get a double list of these fields (because I've got about 50 of them). Any ideas?

[EDIT 2]
Turns out that it did work with the example above, which was a simplified version of my own code. In my own code however, I'm not using simple a field, but an item in a dict. I updated the code above and made a snippet below to show the problem:

```js
var MainController = function($scope){
    $scope.the_field = {};
    $scope.the_field.item = false;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MainController">
  parent: {{the_field.item}}
  <div ng-if="!the_field.item">
    child: {{the_field.item}}<br>
    <input ng-model="the_field.item" type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use a directive to do this. You have to use 2 variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can clone the source object. Like this:

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.the_field = false;
  $scope.the_field_clone = angular.copy($scope.the_field);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{the_field}}
  <div ng-if="!the_field_clone">
    <input ng-model="$parent.the_field" type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

http://jsbin.com/ditoka/edit?html,js

**Update - option 2 - Directive**

```js
angular.module('app', []).
controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.the_field = false;
}).
directive('customIf', function() {
  return {
    scope: {
      customIf: '='
    },
    link: function(scope, element, attrs) {
      if (!scope.customIf) {
        element.remove();  
      }
    }
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
  {{the_field}}
  <div custom-if="!the_field">
    <input ng-model="the_field" type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for that, that will indeed work. The problem is however, that I need to do this for about 50 checkboxes. If I would need to do this for all the checkboxes I basically get a double list of my fields, both in the html and in the controller. I would prefer doing it only in the template because that would give me one single spot where the whole list of items is. Otherwise I need to edit in two places if things are removed or added to the list (and they will). Would you know of a way that I can do this only in the template?

Answer (score 1):

It works with the code of your question, try it out ;)

(see [What are Scopes?](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope))

```js
var MainController = function($scope){
    $scope.the_field = false;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MainController">
  parent: {{the_field}}
  <div ng-if="!the_field">
    child: {{the_field}}<br>
    <input ng-model="the_field" type="checkbox">
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Good catch! I simplified the code for my question, but it turns out I simplified it a bit too much. I'm actually not using `the_field`, but in my own code `the_field` is a dict containing some items. I added a snippet to my initial question to show what my problem is. Any idea how I can solve that?

Answer (score 0):

The answer to your updated question:
You can use another property in your model, edited when the first click occurs...

```js
var MainController = function($scope){
    $scope.model = {init: true, the_field: false};
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="" ng-controller="MainController">
    parent: {{model.the_field}}
    <div ng-if="!model.the_field || !model.init">
        <input ng-model="model.the_field" type="checkbox" ng-click="model.init=false;">
    </div>
</div>
```